# Possible to take a svg made in illustrator and turn it into a raphael path to then animate?

Tags: svg, raphael

Would like to take my logo made in illustrator then turn it into a svg so that i can then use Raphael to animate it. I know how to make a simple image by creating my own path using lineTo.
 Didn't know if this is possible or not.

Thank you

Comment: I think I helped with the question, accept it so it won't show unanswered

Answer (score 2):

Once you save your logo created with `Illustrator` as `svg` file, there is a way to convert the **`SVG into a Raphael object`** and then you can use it with Raphael library.

Chack out this website: **http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE.php**

If you can, open the page with `Firefox`. `Chrome` messes up the page. ***Good Luck.***

Answer (score 0):

Well, if its just the path you need without the colors, stroke widths etc, i would save the illustrator logo as an SVG and then open it with a text editor(say Notepad).

From there i would extract the d attribute as a path and manually add the rest of its ''features'' like colors,stroke widths etc.

Comment: In case there are many different paths in the logo the ''Weld'' or ''Union'' command will group all paths into one